# R-data Manupulation

Tags: r

I have a data set of 176plant population in 3 replicates(R1, R2, R3). I made a table(below).now I want to take a average value of R1, R2, and R3 of each individual and write the value in a new column of my .CSV data file. I can do it in R?
Please help.

```
##demo file

| geno  | trait1    | trait2    | trait3    | trait4    |
|------ |--------   |--------   |--------   |--------   |
| 1_R1  | 1.891     | 2.561     | 0.9       | 11        |
| 1_R2  | 10.341    | 2.121     | 0.6       | 2         |
| 1_R3  | 9.451     | 6.781     | 4.56      | 7         |
| 2_R1  | 11.09     | 9.191     |           | 8         |
```

Comment: If your data is called df: `transform(df, meantrait1 = ave(trait1, geno, FUN = mean))` to add the mean of trait1 per geno. This type of question has been answered many times so you'll find the answer if you look a little harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to do this in `dplyr`.  Assuming that the "geno" column has both the "id" and "geno" information, we need to first split up the "geno" column.  Use `separate` to do this, and then get the mean of each `trait` column with `mutate_each`.  There is an option in `mutate_each` to select the column names.  We can use either `starts_with`, `end_with`, `contains`, `matches` etc...  Here, I am specifying the column not to be taken by `-`.  After that, `unite` the columns "geno1" and "id" to a single column "geno", `left_join` with original `df`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
 df1 <- df %>%
            separate(geno, c('id', 'geno1'))%>%
            group_by(id)%>%
            mutate_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=TRUE)),-geno1) %>%
            unite(geno, id, geno1)
 colnames(df1)[-1] <- paste(colnames(df1)[-1], 'mean', sep="_")
 left_join(df, df1, by='geno')
 #  geno trait1 trait2 trait3 trait4 trait1_mean trait2_mean trait3_mean
 #1 1_R1  1.891  2.561   0.90     11    7.227667       3.821        2.02
 #2 1_R2 10.341  2.121   0.60      2    7.227667       3.821        2.02
 #3 1_R3  9.451  6.781   4.56      7    7.227667       3.821        2.02
 #4 2_R1 11.090  9.191     NA      8   11.090000       9.191         NaN
 #  trait4_mean
 #1    6.666667
 #2    6.666667
 #3    6.666667
 #4    8.000000
```

Or comparatively more easier with `data.table`.  Convert the `data.frame` to `data.table` using `setDT`. Create new columns `nm1` by assigning (`:=`) to the mean of each of the columns.  We use `lapply(..)` to get the mean of the columns specified in `.SDcols`.

```
 library(data.table)
 nm1 <- paste(colnames(df)[-1], 'mean', sep="_")
 setDT(df)[, (nm1):= lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE),
              list(id=sub('_.*', '', geno)),.SDcols=2:5]
```

Or if you just need "mean summary" of each "column" by "id", you could do in `base R`.  Make sure to specify `na.action=na.pass` or else the "default" settings will remove the entire row, resulting in different output.

```
df$id <- sub('_.*', '', df$geno)
aggregate(.~id, df[-1], FUN=mean, na.action=na.pass)
#  id    trait1 trait2 trait3   trait4
#1  1  7.227667  3.821   2.02 6.666667
#2  2 11.090000  9.191     NA 8.000000
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(geno = c("1_R1", "1_R2", "1_R3", "2_R1"), 
trait1 = c(1.891, 10.341, 9.451, 11.09), trait2 = c(2.561, 2.121, 6.781, 
9.191), trait3 = c(0.9, 0.6, 4.56, NA), trait4 = c(11L, 2L, 7L, 8L
)), .Names = c("geno", "trait1", "trait2", "trait3", "trait4"
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me out. This will work for me.